# For loop that creates a new variable in a dataframe, run over multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

Hi all—I am trying to run a for loop that creates a new variable based on some conditions over a vector of multiple dataframes in R (that are split by observation ID), and am having some trouble.

```
Dat_nations <- split(Dat, Dat$newccode)
```

^This creates my vector of 143 dataframes, grouped by country code.  The for loop that I want to apply to each country dataframe is:

```
for (i in 1:(length(df1$timeafter)
                    -1){
  df1$timeafter[i+1] <- (df1$newdate[i+1]-df1$newdate[i])  
}
```

Essentially, I am creating a new variable that counts the number of days an observation came after the preceding observation from within a specific country (they are arranged in order by date).  But I can't figure out how to run this over all dataframes iteratively, modifying each, and then combining them all back together.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the canonical way to deal with a list of frames is using `lapply`, though a `for` loop can certainly work; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227 for several discussions about "list of frames".

A note: `length(df)` is the number of *columns*, not the number of *rows*. (Further, `1:length(x)` can be a mistake if used programmatically: if for some reason the argument `x` is length 0, then one would want/expect this to return a vector of length 0, but instead it returns `1:0` aka `c(1, 0)`. To iterate more safely over columns, use `seq_along(x)`; to iterate safely over rows, use `seq_len(nrow(x))`.

I think you can do what you need with:

```r
lapply(Dat_nations, function(dat) {
  dat$timeafter <- c(NA, diff(dat$newdate))
  dat
})
```

Incidentally, if you are intending to then combine this back into a single frame (for any number of reasons), this can be done without `split` (and likely faster) with:

```r
Dat$timeafter <- ave(Dat$newdate, Dat$newccode, FUN = function(z) c(NA, diff(z)))
```

Last note: `diff(z)` when `z` is of class `Date` or `POSIXt` will return a number of class `difftime`. This means that instead of showing for instance `3`, on the console it will show `Time difference of 3 days`. While it looks like a string, it is still a number ... `dput(diff(Sys.Date()+c(0,3)))+10` (adding 10 to the difference) still works. **However**, the units can change (esp if `POSIXt`) which is disrupting. One easy way around this is to force it with something like

```r
diff(Sys.Date() + c(0, 3))
# Time difference of 3 days
as.numeric(diff(Sys.Date() + c(0, 3)), units = "days")
# [1] 3
as.numeric(diff(Sys.Date() + c(0, 3)), units = "hours")
# [1] 72
```

Comment: Super helpful!  One final Q: 

I am receiving the following error from R when I run the ave command:

```
Error in as.Date.default(value) : do not know how to convert 'value' to class “Date”
```

This of course regards the the 'date' classification of the variable, but it seemingly isn't able to move past that and actually conduct calculations.  Oddly, it works fine when I use lapply.

Comment: I don't know about that error, I'd need to "see" it in action, tbh.